# Get element that matches value in multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multi-dimensional array.

I want to get the element in the array that matches a certain value.

Array:

```
$userdb=Array
(
    (0) => Array
        (
            (id) => '0',
            (name) => 'Sandra Shush',
            (url) => 'urlof100'
        ),

    (1) => Array
        (
            (id) => '1',
            (name) => 'Stefanie Mcmohn',
            (pic_square) => 'urlof100'
        ),

    (2) => Array
        (
            (id) => '2',
            (name) => 'Michael',
            (pic_square) => 'urlof40489'
        )
);
```

Code to get array element where `id = 2`:

```
$key = array_search(2, array_column($userDB, 'id'));
```

Current code is not returning anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just loop over the array, and when you find the element that meets your criteria, stop.

```
$id = 2;
$found_user = null;
foreach ($userdb as $user) {
    if ($user['id'] == $id) {
        $found_user = $user;
        break;
    }
}
```

With your current code, `$key` should be set to `2`, but remember that variable names are case sensitive, (so `$userdb != $userDB`). If you just want to get the key, it should work as long as you are using the correct variable name. If you want to get the entire element, then you can use the key returned by array_search directly:

```
$user = $userdb[array_search(2, array_column($userdb, 'id'))];
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
<?php
$userdb=Array
(
    (0) => Array
        (
            (id) => '0',
            (name) => 'Sandra Shush',
            (url) => 'urlof100'
        ),

    (1) => Array
        (
            (id) => '1',
            (name) => 'Stefanie Mcmohn',
            (pic_square) => 'urlof100'
        ),

    (2) => Array
        (
            (id) => '2',
            (name) => 'Michael',
            (pic_square) => 'urlof40489'
        )
);

 //echo $userdb[0]['id']; //-result index id 0 => 0-//
//echo $userdb[1]['id']; //-result index id 1 => 1-//
//echo $userdb[2]['id']; //-result index id 2 => 2-//
$id = 2;
foreach($userdb as $value)
{
 if($value['id'] == $id)
 {
  var_dump($value);
  break;
 }
}
?>
```

Comment: How does this answer the OP's question? You are just looping over the array and echoing the `id` value.