# Check if a key value exist into a multidimensional array with PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I've the following array in PHP:

```
Array
(
    [Europa] => Array
        (
            [country] => France
            [capital] => Paris
        ),
        (
            [country] => Spain
            [capital] => Madrid
        )
    [Asia] => Array
        (
            [country] => Russia
            [capital] => Moscow
        )
)
```

How can I loop into this array to search that a country named France exist into Europa ?

Thanks.

Comment: A simple foreach loop with a condition should be the simpliest way ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get element that matches value in multi-dimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31932519/get-element-that-matches-value-in-multi-dimensional-array)

Comment: @Flyzzx, the simplest but not the best.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `array_column` to extract all data from a column in a multidimensional array. Use `array_column` to check if a string is in an array.

```
$arr = array
(
    "Europa" => array(
        array(
            "country" => 'France',
            "capital" => 'Paris',
        ),
        array(
            "country" => 'Spain',
            "capital" => 'Madrid',
        ),
    ),
    "Asia" => array(
        array(
            "country" => 'Russia',
            "capital" => 'Moscow',
        )
    )
);

$continent = "Europa";
$country = "France";

$isExist = in_array($country,array_column($arr[$continent],'country'));
```

This will result to

```
1
```